# 2010 Access vba moving to different records in ADO

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010, ado

I have a need to update a record either (n) records before or after the current record using ADO.

I have the code to open, read through all the selected records and close.

What I'm wondering is if there's a way to change the current record pointer.  For example, I'd like to do something like this:

```
i=1
Do until rs.EOF
  If i > 5 then
    Field2=rs!Field1
    rs!CurrentRecordPointer = i-3
    'update Field2 in this record
    rs!CurrentRecordPointer = i+3
  End If
  i = i + 1
  rs.MoveNext
Loop
```

Is this possible, or will I need to use an array?

Comment: Does it have to be ADO? I've found DAO recordsets to be better for making updates in iteration.

Comment: I'm all ears... I don't know how to use DAO, only ADO. Will it require a lot of changes to the code and how would I reference a record +/- the current record?  Thanks

Comment: Since I only need three arrays and only for a few records, I decided to save data as I process through the records in arrays and then set the fields in the current record based on the values in the arrays.  I am still interested in DAO and doing this, so if someone has a good pointer to a webpage with examples, I'd appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a DAO object reference you can iterate through your records and update them.

```
Dim db As Database, myRecordset As Recordset
Set db = CurrentDb()

sqlString = "SELECT myfield FROM myTable"

Set myRecordset = db.OpenRecordset(sqlString, dbOpenDynaset, dbSeeChanges)

myRecordset.MoveFirst

Do While myRecordset.EOF = False
    myRecordset.Edit
    myRecordset.Fields("myfield ").Value = newValue
    myRecordset.Update
    myRecordset.MoveNext
Loop
```

Comment: Thanks, @jshort.  This is what I needed.